# Entity Framework 5 Code First Migrations: Get database script

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I've a project following the course of [John Papa about SPA](http://www.johnpapa.net/building-single-page-apps-with-knockout-jquery-and-web-api-ndash-the-story-begins).
So, my architecture is as follows:

```
**proj.Data.Data**
    /Configuration     
      Mappings of the entities with Fluent
    ProjContext.cs
    ProjInitializer.cs
    EFRepository.cs
    /Migrations folder

**proj.Data.Model**
    Pocos (Entity Framework 5 Code First)
    No reference to Entity Framework

**proj.Data.Contracts**
    Interface for IRepository and IProjContext

**proj.UI.Web**
    MVC 4/WebApi project
```

I had an existing database and I ran reverse engineering of Entity Framework to get the entities and separated the context from the entities (in two different projects as shown above)

Then I ran (selecting proj.Data.Data from the PackageManager Console drop down):

```
Enable-Migrations -force -StartupProjectName "Proj.Data.Data"
add-migration InitialSchema
Update-Database
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase
```

I only see in the folder Migrations in the proj.Data.Data project a file named 201211091944388_InitialSchema with the up and down methods empty. No MigrationHistory table created.

What do I need to run to get the sql script to generate the database from scratch with all the tables I have got from the entities?

Thanks! Guillermo.

**NOTE:** I have .Data projects in a solution folder named Data and Web project in a solution folder named UI, Should I take any extra step because of that?

Comment: Have not tried, but you might try adding `-TargetMigration InitialSchema` to the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't work with the reverse engineering, but I made the model again following all the conventions and it worked.

BTW, if we run the enable-migrations command on an existing database it will not create __MigrationHistory table nor the Initial script. This is as design to avoid changes in the existing database.
Thanks anyways.